# How to input unknown number of integers as uesr input in C++

Tags: c++

I want to get an unknown number of integers separated by space as user input. How can I store them in an array?

Answer (score -1):

You could keep changing the size of the array (since you don't know how big to make it).  Or use a data structure (like a vector) designed to change size.

Comment: In which case would you ever use your first suggestion?

Comment: How can I stop the loop? As an example, if I know the number of inputs I can use a statement like this, while(i<=n){cin >> array[i]}

Comment: @Rotem: If you were required to use an array.

Comment: @LamuduMohotti: That depends on the format of the input, and is a separate question from how to store them.